# Use Google Sheets as JSON feed for image carousel

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, carousel, getjson

I am trying to build an image carousel that uses a Google sheet as the source for the information.  I can get the carousel to work if I hard code the JSON, but I am having issues getting the Google Sheet JSON working.

I have opened everything up for viewing that I am working on:
[Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qolqEsn-hxkRwGfyY1O5ttWB9KzqB7MpgNNF6t3mfvk/edit?usp=sharing) (the script that creates the JSON output can be accessed through Tools/Script Editor)
[Google Sheet JSON Output](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzpOcYAX9CrBxGKyQ18Nupe9EzGU-Byl7_A-fY-TSd1zbcvAw/exec)
 
[Google Apps Script Project](https://script.google.com/d/1Wt84CBowMQgMPjrTSOoWqMU8LRAQR9unNXhEtknP6haMazPuapKj2gnk/edit?usp=sharing)

**Here is the Content Service Web App** (generates the JSON from the Google Sheet):

```
// The name of the spreadsheet from the browser location bar.
// Copy after 'key=' until before the next URL parameter beginning w/&
var SPREADSHEET_ID = '1qolqEsn-hxkRwGfyY1O5ttWB9KzqB7MpgNNF6t3mfvk';
var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SPREADSHEET_ID);//Defines the source spreadsheet, in this example, the source is the current spreadsheet.
var source_sheet = source.getSheetByName("Sheet1");//Enter the name between the quotes of the sheet within the specified source spreadsheet that holds the data you want to transfer  
var lastRow = source_sheet.getLastRow();//For checking last row with data in cell and formatting range
var lastColumn = source_sheet.getLastColumn();//For checking last row with data in cell and formatting range
var source_range = source_sheet.getRange(1,1,lastRow,lastColumn);//(StartRow,StartColumn,NumberofRowstoGet,NumberofColumnstoGet)  
// The name of the sheet, displayed in a tab at the bottom of the spreadsheet.
// Default is 'Sheet1' if it's the first sheet.
var SHEET_NAME = 'Sheet1';

function doGet(request) {
//  var callback = request.parameters.jsonp;
  var callback = request.parameters.callback;
  var json = callback + '(' + Utilities.jsonStringify(source_range.getValues()) + ')';

  return ContentService.createTextOutput(json).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT);
}

// Testing to see if the jsonp parameter is being used properly.
function testDoGet() {
  var request = {parameters: {jsonp: 'callback'}};
  var results = doGet(request);
  Logger.log(results.getContent());
}
```

**Below is a working code snippet with the hard coded JSON commented out**, using the feed from the spreadsheet.  Again, the script is fully functional using the hard coded JSON, but does not work when I attempt to use the feed URL.

```js
        $(function(){
            $.getJSON('https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzpOcYAX9CrBxGKyQ18Nupe9EzGU-Byl7_A-fY-TSd1zbcvAw/exec?callback=?', 
            function(json) {
//                console.log(json);                                               //Testing
//                console.log(json[0][0]);                                         //Testing
                var mhtml = '<ul>';
            
                for (var i = 1; i < json.length; i++){                             //For each item in the json array 
//                    console.log('image: ' + json[i][0]);                         //Log the array field
//                    console.log('title: ' + json[i][1]);                         //Log the array field
//                    console.log('desc: ' + json[i][2]);                          //Log the array field
                    mhtml += '<li><div class="img-responsive"><img src="https://images1-focus-opensocial.googleusercontent.com/gadgets/proxy?url='+json[i][0]+'&container=focus&resize_w=665" /></div>';
                    mhtml += '<div class="desc"><h1 class="title">'+json[i][1]+'</h1>';
                    mhtml += '<p class="expert">'+json[i][2]+'</p></div>';
                    mhtml += '</li>';
                };
                mhtml += '</ul>';
                $('.slider').append($(mhtml));
                slideshow();
            });


            function slideshow() {
//                console.log('running slideshow');                                //Testing
//                console.log('slider length: ' + $(".slider ul> li").length);     //Testing
                $(".slider ul> li:gt(0)").css("opacity" , "0");
                var j = 0;
                var delay = 3000; //millisecond delay between cycles
          
                function cycleThru(){
                    var jmax = $(".slider ul> li").length -1;
                    $(".slider ul> li:eq(" + j + ")")
                        .animate({"opacity" : "1.0"} ,400)
                        .animate({"opacity" : "1"}, delay)
                        .animate({"opacity" : "0"}, 400, 
                        function(){
                            (j == jmax) ? j=0 : j++;
                            cycleThru();
                        });
                };

                cycleThru();
  
            }
        });
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Yanone+Kaffeesatz:400,700);

*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz';
}

h1 {
    font-size: 3em;
    font-family: arial;
}

p {
    font-size: 1em;
    font-family: arial;
}

ul li {  margin: 0;
    padding: 0;list-style:none}

.slider {
    display: block;
    min-height: 345px;
    max-width: 665px;
    margin: auto;
    border: 12px rgba(255,255,240,1) solid;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    margin-top: 20px;
    position: relative;
}

.slider ul{  
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 640px;
    overflow:hidden}

.slider>ul>li {
    height: 320px;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
}

.slider >ul>li>img {
    margin: auto;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 345px;
    max-width: 665px;
}

.desc {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 260px;
    z-index: 1000;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,240,0.5);
   
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 7px;
    border-top-right-radius: 15px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.4/material.min.js"></script>
    <?!= include('css'); ?>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="slider"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the callback parameter to your URL.

```
 $.getJSON('https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzpOcYAX9CrBxGKyQ18Nupe9EzGU-Byl7_A-fY-TSd1zbcvAw/exec?callback=?', ...
```

In your contentservice app:

```
function doGet(request) {
  var callback = request.parameters.callback;
  var json = callback + '(' + Utilities.jsonStringify(source_range.getValues()) + ')';
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(json).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response.  I updated the code above and can now get json in the console.log.  Now I am getting this error: jquery.min.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I have this working now and have updated the code above.  Thanks to @spencer-easton for helping with the JSON.  Once I got the feed working, I had to make changes to get it to work.  Significant changes to the original code to highlight are:

**Added a for loop to iterate through the array that results from the JSON:**

```
for (var i = 1; i < json.length; i++){                             //For each item in the json array 
    mhtml += '<li><div class="img-responsive"><img src="https://images1-focus-opensocial.googleusercontent.com/gadgets/proxy?url='+json[i][0]+'&container=focus&resize_w=665" /></div>';
    mhtml += '<div class="desc"><h1 class="title">'+json[i][1]+'</h1>';
    mhtml += '<p class="expert">'+json[i][2]+'</p></div>';
    mhtml += '</li>';
};
```

**Removed $(document).ready from the function that cycled the carousel, and instead called it at the end of the json response function:**

```
    $('.slider').append($(mhtml));
    slideshow();
});


function slideshow() {
    $(".slider ul> li:gt(0)").css("opacity" , "0");
    var j = 0;
    var delay = 3000; //millisecond delay between cycles

    function cycleThru(){
       var jmax = $(".slider ul> li").length -1
```

Comment: Thanks for posting up the follow-up